# How can I check if the curse of dimensionality negatively affects my clustering results

Tags: clustering, high-dimensional

I would like to cluster 80 days using k-means. Each of the 80 days contains 4 time series (temperature, solar radiation, electricity demand, electricity price) with 288 values each. So all in all I have $4*288=1152$ values for each day and I would like to cluster the days such that similar days with regard to these 4 time series combined will be grouped into the same cluster. For this purpose I use the following code, that I was advised to use (at least for the scaling part) from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73491673/strange-results-when-scaling-data-using-scikit-learn:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

data_Unscaled = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User1/Desktop/data_Unscaled.csv", sep=";", header=None)

X = data_Unscaled.to_numpy()
X_narrow = np.array([X[:, i*288:(i+1)*288].ravel() for i in range(4)]).T
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_narrow_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_narrow)
X_scaled = np.array([X_narrow_scaled[i*288:(i+1)*288, :].T.ravel() for i in range(80)])

kmeans = KMeans(init="random", n_clusters=3, n_init=10, max_iter=300, random_state=42)
kmeans.fit(X_scaled)

print(f"resultClustering Example Day 1: {kmeans.predict((X[20].reshape(1, -1)))}")
print(f"resultClustering Example Day 2: {kmeans.predict((X[30].reshape(1, -1)))}")
print(f"resultClustering Example Day 3: {kmeans.predict((X[40].reshape(1, -1)))}")
print(f"resultClustering Example Day 4: {kmeans.predict((X[23].reshape(1, -1)))}")
print(f"resultClustering Example Day 5: {kmeans.predict((X[10].reshape(1, -1)))}")
```

In the linked answer it was assumed that my results would suffer from the curse of dimensionality as I have just 80 points in a 1152-dimensional space. Can anyone tell me how can I check if the curse of dimensionality negatively affects the results? I made some test predictions and the are not all grouped into the same cluster which should be correct.

Here is the unscaled input data with shape (80,1152): https://filetransfer.io/data-package/CfbGV9Uk#link

Comment: Unfortunately, the curse of dimensionality prevents us from determining the effects of the curse of dimensionality ;)

Comment: @JohnMadden: Thanks John for your comment. But is there no way to determine the quality of the clustering and thus try to infer, whether the curse of dimensionality is active or not in my case?

Comment: to be slightly more serious and maybe even useful, the biggest threat posed to a method like Kmeans in high dimension might could be the meaningfulness of Euclidean distance in high dimension; may be worth trying different metrics and seeing how results change.

Comment: You have more dimensions than points. This is not only the curse of dimensionality problem but primarily the singularity/multicollinearity problem. The real number of dimensions of your data is 80-1=79 at max. Which is still many.

Comment: @JohnMadden: Thanks John for your answer. Unfortunately with scikit-learn you can't specify different metrics for kmeans (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529625/is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikit-learn-k-means). And what do you mean by "seeing how results change"? How can I see if the results are good or not? This is also my base question: How can I see if the curse of dimensionality affects my clustering results?

Comment: @ttnphns: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by "singularity/multicollinearity problem"? And how did you infer the real number of dimensions in my data to be 79? I would disagree as I have 80 days with 4 time series each that have 288 values. So I think that I have 1152 dimensions for each of the 80 "datapoints".

Comment: n points span, maximum, n-1 dim linear space. (2 points spread a line, 3 points spread a plane, etc.) So if you have more dimentioms than this, you have excessive dimensionality. 2 points on a plane: the only sufficient dimension is the line connecting them two, and the other (perprendicular to it) dimension is empty (zero for all the ponts), it is therefore unnecessary.

Comment: @PeterBe I'm taking about things like Elbow plots or just manually looking at two days you know to be similar and seeing whether they end up in the same clusters. But while we're at it, might as well visualize your data by reducing them to 2 dimensions using something like PCA or MDS or tSNE or a GTM or something else?

Comment: @ttnphns: Thanks for your answer. I have to admit that I don't understand what you are saying and still wondering how you say that I have 79 dimensions (instead of the 1152 dimensions). I still would disagree with this statement about the number of dimensions.

Comment: @JohnMadden: Thanks for your answer. I will try to use the elbow plot. Maybre one general idea is to not use the time series directly but to calculate aggregated statistics for them like the mean, minimum value, maximum value, variance. This way, I would reduce the dimensionality while still having meaningfull features (opposed to PCA).

Comment: @PeterBe Yes! Absolutely do this first. Start with simple things where you can tell if something is dead wrong, and slowly ramp up the complexity as needed/desired, in general with stats :)